# Eigenvector Parameter Substitution Order

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So basic question about finding eigenvectors of the matrix below
$$\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 & 2\\\ 2 & 5 & 2\\\ 2 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

i have already solved for the eigenvalues and got$$\lambda =  3,3,9$$

for the double $$\lambda =  3$$  we get the equation

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$$

after doing row ops.

now i did the substitution $$x_1 = t$$$$  x_2 = s $$

which gives us $$x_3 = -s-t$$

thus we get 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\x_2 \\x_3\\\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}t \\s \\-s-t\\\end{pmatrix} =t \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1\\\end{pmatrix}+ s\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1 \\-1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

now the reference solutions i have been given did the substitution differently
 $$x_1 = -s-t$$$$  x_2 = s $$
$$x_3 = t$$

and thus

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\x_2 \\x_3\\\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}-s-t \\s \\t\\\end{pmatrix} =s \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\1 \\0\\\end{pmatrix}+ t\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\0 \\1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

now did I do make a mistake somewhere or are the answers actually equivalent? (they seem to have row equivalence...)

Answer (score 1):

Let your solution be $u_1, u_2$. They are linearly independent.

Let their solution be $v_1, v_2$. They are also linearly independent.

Notice that $v_2=-u_1$, $v_2 = -u_1+u_2$, they are equivalent.